# MSI Installer Application Installation Folder Location

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer

I am using Advanced Installer in order to install a file in the following folder location:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel

What I can't determine is the proper way of accessing this folder through the Advanced Installer. I've tried stating the address as [AppDataFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName] but that results in the following:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Manufacturer\ProductName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to set the install folder like this:

```
[AppDataFolder]Microsoft\Excel
```

Give it a try and see if this is what you need.

Comment: Perfect, this does exactly what I need. Thanks.